# DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got the number 0 instead

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create a flocking model, however when my sliders are at specific areas or my population is below 100 I get the stated error any help would be greatly appreciated

I know that it has something to do with my "to flock" procedure

```
turtles-own [
  flockmates
  nearest-neighbor
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles population
    [set color white
      set size 5
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [flock wiggle]
  tick
end







to flock
  find-flockmates
  ifelse any? flockmates
  [find-nearest-neighbor]
  [explore]
  ifelse distance nearest-neighbor < perspace
  [separate]
  [ifelse distance nearest-neighbor < nearview [set color orange]
    [align]] 
end
```

```
to find-flockmates
  set flockmates other turtles in-cone maxview vision-angle
end

to find-nearest-neighbor
  set nearest-neighbor min-one-of flockmates [distance myself]
end



to separate
  rt 180 
  set color 13
end

to wiggle
  rt random 20
  lt random 20
  fd 1
end

to align  
   face nearest-neighbor
  set color yellow
end


to turn-towards [new-heading max-turn]
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings new-heading heading) max-turn
end

to turn-away [new-heading max-turn]
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings heading new-heading) max-turn
end


to turn-at-most [turn max-turn] 
  ifelse abs turn > max-turn
    [ ifelse turn > 0
        [ rt max-turn ]
        [ lt max-turn ] ]
    [ rt turn ]
end

to explore
  let r random exploration-option
  ifelse r = 0
   [rt search-angle]
   [lt search-angle]
   set color white
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mre] of your problems: this will help you receive (more meaningful) answers and will help others save time while trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a reproducible example of your problem, but the reason must be the following...

The error message there is very informative: `distance` expected to find an agent but got the number 0 instead. This is most likely referringt to `distance nearest-neighbor`. We know that 0 is the default value of custom variables, which means that when this error appears it is because some turtle has not yet been able to find a `nearest-neighbor` based on `find nearest-neighbor` (which in turn means that it found nobody in `find flockmates`, based on the `ifelse any? flockmates` part).

I have no idea what happens in `explore`, but it doesn't really matter: you need to adjust your code so that it doesn't ask turtles to do something with `nearest-neighbor` if they haven't found a `nearest-neighbor` yet.